# Inject Expression from One Environment and Evaluate in Another

Tags: r, rlang, tidyeval

## Update

It turns out that the function [`rlang::expr_interp()`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/expr_interp.html) essentially meets my goal.

```
unquo_2 <- function(expr, inj_env = rlang::caller_env(), eval_env = NULL) {
  # Capture verbatim the argument passed to 'expr'...
  expr_quo <- rrlang::enquo0(expr)
  # ...and extract it literally as an expression.
  expr_lit <- rlang::quo_get_expr(expr_quo)
  
  # Unquote that expression in the context of the injection environment.
  expr_inj <- rlang::expr_interp(expr_lit, inj_env)
  
  # As desired, return either the unquoted expression itself...
  if(rlang::is_null(eval_env)) {
    expr_inj
  }
  # ...or the result of evaluating it in the evaluation environment.
  else {
    rlang::eval_bare(expr_inj, eval_env)
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, `expr_interp()` is [**deprecated**](https://lifecycle.r-lib.org/articles/stages.html#deprecated) in favor of [`inject()`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/inject.html), which neither accommodates a separate injection environment nor returns the expression before evaluating it.

---

## Goals

I am developing a package, and I need a function that behaves similarly to [`rlang::inject()`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/inject.html) or [`rlang::qq_show()`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/qq_show.html).  This function should be of the form

```
unquo <- function(expr, inj_env) {
  # ...
}
```

which accepts an expression `expr` and injects the arguments from `inj_env`.  Then it returns the injected expression itself, *without* evaluating it.

For example:

```
library(rlang)



# Arguments to inject from global environment.
a <- sym("a.global")
b <- sym("b.global")


# Arguments to inject from custom environment, which has no parent.
my_env <- new_environment(list(a = sym("a.custom")))



# Injecting from global environment.
unquo(!!a + !!b, global_env())
#> a.global + b.global


# Injecting from custom environment...
unquo(!!a + 1, my_env)
#> a.custom + 1

# ...where 'b' neither exists nor is inherited.
unquo(!!a + !!b, my_env)
#> Error in enexpr(expr) : object 'b' not found
```

## Roadblock

Unfortunately, neither `inject()` nor `qq_show()` suffice.

While `inject()` does have an `env` parameter, this is only for *evaluating* the expression *after* it has been injected.  There is no `inj_env` *from* which the arguments may be injected, as they are always taken from the calling context.

Furthermore, there is no option to return the injected expression *itself*, as `inject()` will always return the result of *evaluating* that expression in `env`.

As for `qq_show()`, it *prints* the injected expression itself, but it does not *return* it as an object: the return value is `NULL`.  Like `inject()`, it also lacks an `inj_env` from which arguments are injected.

## Attempts

I've had some success with this approach here:

```
unquo_1 <- function(expr, inj_env) {
  inj_expr <- substitute(inject(quote(expr)))
  eval_bare(inj_expr, inj_env)
}
```

The idea is that when we call something like `unquo_1(!!a + 1, global_env())`, it will create an `inj_expr` of `inject(quote(!!a + 1))`.  This will be evaluated in `inj_env`, which here includes the object `a`: the symbol `a.global`.  So `inject()` will unquote `!!a` to get `quote(a.global + 1)`, which it then evaluates (also in `inj_env`).  The result is simply the expression `a.global + 1`.

As with my illustration of behavior in **Goals**, this often works as expected:

```
unquo_1(!!a + 1, global_env())
#> a.global + 1

unquo_1(!!a + !!b, global_env())
#> a.global + b.global

unquo_1(!!a + !!z, global_env())
#> Error in enexpr(expr) : object 'z' not found
```

#### *However*, there is a subtle yet *critical* edge case, which defeats the entire purpose:

```
unquo_1(!!a + 1, my_env)
#> Error in inject(quote(!!a + 1)) : could not find function "inject"
```

Unlike `a`, the function `inject` is an object *undefined* in `my_env` and its environmental ancestors.  If it were defined differently, as with `env_bind(my_env, inject = base::stop)`, then its behavior would still be entirely unhelpful.  The same applies for the functions `quote`, `` `!` ``, and so forth.

---

The best solution I've found is to redefine `inj_expr` to fully qualify `rlang::inject()` and [`base::quote()`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/substitute.html):

```
unquo_1 <- function(expr, inj_env) {
  inj_expr <- substitute(rlang::inject(base::quote(expr)))
  eval_bare(inj_expr, inj_env)
}
```

On its own, this "solution" would simply produce another error

```
Error in rlang::inject : could not find function "::"
```

because `` `::` `` is unavailable in `inj_env`.  But with inspiration from [`data_mask`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/as_data_mask.html#ref-examples)ing conventions

> ```
>  # A common situation where you'll want a multiple-environment mask
>  # is when you include functions in your mask. In that case you'll
>  # put functions in the top environment and data in the bottom. This
>  # will prevent the data from overwriting the functions.
>  top <- new_environment(list(`+` = base::paste, c = base::paste))
> ```

the simple tweak [`env_bind`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/env_bind.html)`` (inj_env, "::" = `::`) `` will make the function [`` `::`() ``](https://rdrr.io/r/base/ns-dblcolon.html) accessible in `inj_env`.  This one tweak thus facilitates access via `pkg::fn` to any function `fn` in any package `pkg`!

#### However, this still exposes `unquo_1()` to **naming collisions**.  What if someone wanted to inject the expression `` !!`::` `` with an alternative function named `::`?.

I really do want the contents of `inj_env` (and its parents) restricted to *exactly* what the user supplies.

## Suggestions

I have experimented unsuccessfully with [function factories](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/function-factories.html#factory-fundamentals), for the sake of associating an injector with a custom environment.  The documentation for [`rlang::env_bind_lazy()`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/env_bind.html#ref-examples) still seems promising

> ```
>  # By default the expressions are evaluated in the current
>  # environment. For instance we can create a local binding and refer
>  # to it, even though the variable is bound in a different
>  # environment:
>  who <- "mickey"
>  env_bind_lazy(env, name = paste(who, "mouse"))
>  env$name
>  #> [1] "mickey mouse"
>  
>  # You can specify another evaluation environment with `.eval_env`:
>  eval_env <- env(who = "minnie")
>  env_bind_lazy(env, name = paste(who, "mouse"), .eval_env = eval_env)
>  env$name
>  #> [1] "minnie mouse"
> ```

but I lack the expertise to leverage it.

---

Alternatively, examining the source code for `rlang::inject()`

```
function (expr, env = caller_env()) 
{
    .External2(rlang_ext2_eval, enexpr(expr), env)
}
```

highlights the importance of [`rlang::enexpr()`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/defusing-advanced.html)

```
function (arg) 
{
    .Call(rlang_enexpr, substitute(arg), parent.frame())
}
```

which in turn suggests that the DLL `rlang:::rlang_enexpr` is essential:

```
$name
[1] "rlang_enexpr"

$address
<pointer: 0x7ff630452a60>
attr(,"class")
[1] "RegisteredNativeSymbol"

$dll
DLL name: rlang
Filename:
         /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/rlang/libs/rlang.so
Dynamic lookup: FALSE

$numParameters
[1] 2

attr(,"class")
[1] "CallRoutine"      "NativeSymbolInfo"
```

This seems to originate [here](https://github.com/r-lib/rlang/blob/b3327104bac9c9fec90fa081fdd9cb321c3f29bb/src/internal/arg.c#L43-L45) as source code in C:

```
r_obj* ffi_enexpr(r_obj* sym, r_obj* frame) {
  return capture(sym, frame, NULL);
}
```

However, I lack the skill in C to trace how unquotation is implemented here, let alone to rewrite `ffi_enexpr` for my own package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Original

```r
a <- sym("a.global")
b <- sym("b.global")

# Note this must be an environment that inherits from
# base. `new_environment()` creates envs that inherit from the empty
# env by default, which means even `::` is not in scope.
# Here we use `env()` which inherits from the current env by default.
my_env <- env(a = sym("a.custom"))

expr2 <- function(expr, env = caller_env()) {
  # Grab the defused expression using base R to avoid processing
  # rlang injection operators
  expr <- substitute(expr)

  # Inject the expression within `expr()` so it can process the
  # operators within `env`. Qualify with `::` because `env`
  # potentially doesn't have `expr()` in scope.
  inject(rlang::expr(!!expr), env)
}

expr2(!!a + !!b, my_env)
#> a.custom + b.global

expr2(!!a + !!b)
#> a.global + b.global
```

## Update [✅](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71541009/inject-expression-from-one-environment-and-evaluate-in-another/71545814#comment126508025_71545814)

You can [inline `expr`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71541009/inject-expression-from-one-environment-and-evaluate-in-another/71545814#comment126466450_71545814) in the call, as implemented [here](https://github.com/r-lib/rlang/issues/1379#issuecomment-1073661639) on GitHub:

```r
expr2 <- function(expr, env = caller_env()) {
  # Grab the defused expression using base R to avoid processing
  # rlang injection operators
  expr <- substitute(expr)

  # Inject the expression within `expr()` so it can process the
  # operators within `env`. Inline `expr` in case it isn't in scope
  inject((!!rlang::expr)(!!expr), env)
}
```

Comment: Thanks @LionelHenry!  I should note that I did try this process before, and my `unquo_1()` function produces essentially the same results.  However, the whole thrust of my question was to deal with a `my_env` that **does _not_ inherit from `base`**: I deliberately chose `my_env <- new_environment(...)`.  Perhaps there is no way to do this other than modifying the C code...

Comment: I should also mention that I did consider the scope of `::`, and I want my approach to work even when **no functions whatsoever** are in scope.  For the moment, my binding of `::` to `my_env` is merely a stopgap solution.

Comment: Then you can inline `expr` in the call: `inject((!!rlang::expr)(!!expr), env)`

Comment: Thanks Lionel!  I have taken the liberty of editing your answer to include this inline solution, which I have marked as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need to store your desired symbols in an environment? It seems if you are just storing symbols/expressions then you can more easily do that in a container like `exprs` and then can use the `with_bindings` function to replace some values. So if you have

```
a <- expr(a.global)
b <- expr(b.global)
my_env <- exprs(a = a.custom)
```

then you can do

```
with_bindings(expr(!!a + 1))
# a.global + 1
with_bindings(expr(!!a + 1), !!!my_env)
# a.custom + 1
with_bindings(expr(!!a + !!z), !!!my_env)
# Error in enexpr(expr) : object 'z' not found
```

Once you have the correct expression, you can evaluate it wherever you like.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @MrFlick!  I do have some reservations, though.  When I run `with_bindings(expr(!!a + !!b), !!!my_env)`, I do get `a.custom + b.global`.  While searching beyond `my_env` *can* be useful behavior, I certainly do want the optionality to restrict bindings to *only* `my_env`: `Error in enexpr(expr) : object 'b' not found`.  I also want airtight robustness against any collisions (like `!!.expr`) with the `.expr` and `.env` arguments to `with_bindings()`.  Is this possible, perhaps with [`env_bind_lazy()`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/env_bind.html#ref-examples)?

Comment: I should also clarify that my approach does **require** that these symbols be stored in an environment, for purposes of inheritance.  This environment can be created from a list, if necessary.